# How to delete attached data disk after the VM is deleted in Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform

I am using Terraform to create on-demand Azure infrastructure for my users. The infrastructure includes VM and 256 GB data disk. At end of the day, the 'Terraform Destroy' will delete the VM. But the data disk is not deleted. Is there a way to delete the attached disk on destroy command?

Comment: Could you show your terraform code?

Comment: yeah. that sounds really weird

Answer (score 0):

If both your 256 Gb disk and your VM are created through the terraform code, you can use
"terraform destroy --target=azurerm_virtual_machine.{VM resource name}", and
"terraform destroy --target=azurerm_managed_disk.{managed disk resource name}".
This deletes your VM and then your disk as well.

In case your disk wasn't created by terraform, you can use "terraform import" to import your disk into terraform code and then delete it using the above.